# Replacement part for bradford water heater thermocouple

Tags: water-heater, thermocouple

I have a bradford water heater and I am trying to replace the thermocouple.  After getting it out, it looks like I can't just replace the thermo but I have to replace a full assembly.  The thermo has a part# on it (`233-46408-04c`) but I am unable to find that specific part# anywhere.  I did see there is a `233-46408-05` but that has been discontinued and one site I went to recommended part# `415-48999-05` as an alternative.

So at this point I am not sure what part I actually need.  Both of the alternatives look like the part I have but the water heater manual says to use exact part# only, so I don't know.

Can I use either of those alternatives or what is my play here?  I have linked some pictures here of my current setup.

https://imgur.com/a/8SHJLbv

Comment: Generally, online appliance parts stores do a pretty good job of cross-referencing old, discontinued part numbers with new OEM-certified replacements. Often, a mfgr will quit making an old part number and replace it with an improved part number that is an exact replacement of the old one. If you're not sure, contact Bradford via their website and ask.